# When one mouse listener in a JPanel is called, they are all being called?

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have a Java GUI code that uses multiple JLabels within a JPanel. Each individual JLabel has a unique mouse listener that is called when the JLabel is clicked. For some reason, when one JLabel is clicked, they are all being called.

Here are the JLabels:

```
car1 = new JLabel(card1); //card1 is just an image icon, no problems there
car2 = new JLabel(card2);
car3 = new JLabel(card3);
```

Mouse Listeners:

```
car1.addMouseListener(new CardGUI("/cards/aceclubsS.gif", car1)); //Sends the path of the new card to be implemented as a JLabel as well as the current JLabel clicked.
car2.addMouseListener(new CardGUI("/cards/aceheartsS.gif", car2));
car3.addMouseListener(new CardGUI("/cards/acespadesS.gif", car3));
```

CardGUI Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardGUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private static JLabel called;
    private static JLabel current;
    private static String tmp;
    private static JLabel temp;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class CardGUI
     */
    public CardGUI(String path, JLabel cur)
    {
        temp = cur;
        tmp = path;
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        current = null;
        called = null;
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        current = null;
        called = null;
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        current = null;
        called = null;
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        current = null;
        called = null;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        ImageIcon ic = GameGUI.createImageIcon(tmp, "");
        called = new JLabel(ic);
        current = temp;
        GameGUI.replace(current, called);
    }
    public static JLabel getCalled()
    {
        return called;
    }
    public static JLabel getCurrent()
    {
        return current;
    }
}
```

The replace method in the original class:

```
public static void replace(JLabel jl1, JLabel jl2)
    {
        JLabel calledr = jl2;
        p2.remove(jl1);
        p2.add(calledr);
        p2.revalidate();
        p2.repaint();
    } //p2 is the panel all of the JLabels are in
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the actual `mouseClicked` method is getting called on all of them?  I suspect that only one of them is getting called.  But `called` and `current` are declared as `static`.  So if one of your listeners updates their value, they will all update.

Comment: The problem is the use of static variables. They're shared by all the instances of `CardGUI`.

Answer (score 1):

Your CardGUI Class uses only static Variables.
static variables only exists one time for all instatnces of the class.
So

```
CardGUI one=new CardGUI("Path", label1)
CardGUI two=new CardGUI("otherPath", label2)
```

one and two share the same tmp, temp, called, current variables. So in line 2 you are overwriting the label1 in line 1.
depending on your display,refreshment, the symbols you are displaying, or the paths are also the same among all Listeners.

greets
reineke

### EDIT:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CardGUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private JLabel called;
    private JLabel current;
    private String tmp;
    private JLabel temp;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class CardGUI
     */
    public CardGUI(String path, JLabel cur)
    {
        temp = cur;
        tmp = path;
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        current = null;
        called = null;
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        current = null;
        called = null;
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        current = null;
        called = null;
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        current = null;
        called = null;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        ImageIcon ic = GameGUI.createImageIcon(tmp, "");
        called = new JLabel(ic);
        current = temp;
        GameGUI.replace(current, called);
    }
    public static JLabel getCalled()
    {
        return called;
    }
    public static JLabel getCurrent()
    {
        return current;
    }
}
```

this should work fine